In Proverbs 8:30, does "Amon" mean "Beloved Child" or "Master Craftsman"?
There is great controversy surrounding this particular word. Many scholars say "amon" is translated as "master workman", but others say that it means "beloved child" or "united together".
Which is it? The surrounding implications are huge, and impact Theology and Christology.


וָאֶהְיֶה אֶצְלוֹ אָמוֹן וָאֶהְיֶה שַׁעֲשׁוּעִים יוֹם  יוֹם מְשַׂחֶקֶת
לְפָנָיו בְּכׇל־עֵת

The word you’re asking about is “אמון” which has the shoresh א-מ-נ which means to rear, bring up, nurse, nurture, foster, train, coach, teach, educate, practice, believe, trust, be faithful/reliable/trusty/established, confirm, verify, authenticate confide in, disclose, reveal, divulge. This shoresh is the same as אמן (amen, commonly said at the end of prayer), אמונה (emunah, faith).
The JPS translates this verse as

I was with Him as a confidant, A source of delight every day,
Rejoicing before Him at all times

Rashi chooses a related, but different translation:

a nursling Heb. אמון, one that was reared beside Him, an expression of
(Lam. 4:5): “They that were reared (האמנים) amid crimson

This word is best translated as “confidant”, “nursling”, or “trusted companion” into English

This matches the LXX rendering. "Close nursling" agrees with "Beloved child", which answers my question. The Unitarians are going to break out into singing and dancing when they hear about this, which removes the biased translation attempt to make Christ be a co-creator with God in the Genesis work. This contradicted so many other passages in Scripture which reveal that God alone created all things.

The Hebrew word
אָמֹון
in this form, when it is not the proper name of a person, אָמֹון only occurs twice in the Old Testament Masoretic text (MT), in Prov. 8:30 and Jer. 52:15.  I searched אמון in the MT and looked at every case.  By far אמון and אמונה occur as adjectives meaning trustworthy, faithfulness, or steadfast.  When a noun, BDB has the following, while referencing some different translations:

אָמוֹן … n.m. artificer, architect, master-workman, as firm and sure in his workmanship: וָאֶהְיֶה אֶצְלוֹ אָמוֹן I was at his side architect, master-workman (   Ges Ew De MV RV, > foster-son AE Ki AV) Pr 8:30; יֶתֶר הָֽאָמוֹן rest of the master-workmen Je 52:15 (Hi Gf De RVm, but rest of the multitude Ges MV RV et al., אמון = המון)—1. אָמוֹן v. supr. p. 51. --
Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 54). Clarendon Press.

The root אמן of this Hebrew word is important in the MT.  It is where we get the word amen.
אָמַן … vb. confirm, support … only Qal Pt. אֹמֵן;—1. as vb. support, nourish 2 K 10:1, 5 Est 2:7. 2. as subst. foster-father Nu 11:12 (J) Is 49:23. 3. אֹמֶנֶת foster-mother, nurse Ru 4:16 2 S 4:4. 4. אֹמְנוֹת pillars, supporters of the door … 5. reliable, faithful, trusty: persons … Hiph. … 1. stand firm … 2. trust, believe: … --
Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 52-53). Clarendon Press.
However, there appears to be a homonym to this root in which both translation possibilities you mention come from

אָמַן (b. h.; √אם, v. אֵם; cmp. אַמָּה) to arrange in lines, array. … —Denom. אוּמָן expert, skilful, whence
Pi. אִמֵּן, אִימֵּן to make skilful, to train. … --
Jastrow, M. (1903). In A Dictionary of the Targumim, the Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi, and the Midrashic Literature and II (Vol. 1, p. 77). Luzac & Co.; G. P. Putnam’s Sons.

However, there is no indication of the root  meaning child, son, or beloved.  That appears to be an attempt to read John 1:1-3 into Prov. 8:30.
Here is even another way אָמוֹן is translated.
  I was with Him as a confidant [אָמוֹן], 
  A source of delight every day, 
  Rejoicing before Him at all times,
                          (Prov. 8:30, JPS1985)


The whole Trinity participated in creation if you believe in the Trinity.

I don't believe I'm the doctrine of the Trinity, but I do think that Jesus was the agent of God in creation.

This is another of the inexplicable quirks of the Strong's list of Hebrew words.  we have three words, 525, 527, 528, all designating the same masculine noun, אָמוֹן (amon) with the same meaning. [526 is a proper name of several people but still the same word.]
Together, these three Strong's listing have the following occurrences: Prov 8:30, Jer 46:25, 52:15, SS 7:1.
Nah 3:8 appears to be the proper name of an Egyptian god and Jer 46:25 might mean "multitude", but this is debatable.
All these words appear to derive from the verb אָמַן (aman) meaning, "to confirm, support", Gen 15:6, 42:20, 45:26, Ex 4:1, 5, 8, 9, etc.
Further, the BDB lexicon also lists the meaning of this noun,  אָמוֹן (amon) as "artificer, architect, master-workman".  The same is true of The Complete Word Study Dictionary by Baker and Carpenter.

So it certainly does not mean "artificer" or "master workman", which reinforces the doctrine that Christ was a co-creator with God! The Arians were right all along!

@JoshuaB - no they were not - Prov 8 is NOT about Christ as the pronouns for "wisdom" are feminine!!!  Prov 8 is simply about the personification of wisdom.  Nothing more.  Do not make the mistake of turning Jesus into a girl at one point and then a boy at another point.

Dottard - "Blessed is the one who listens to Me, watching daily at My gates, waiting beside My doors. For whoever finds Me finds life and obtains favor from the LORD, but he who fails to find Me injures himself; all who hate Me love death.” (Proverbs 8:34-36) How is that not Christ speaking?

Dottard - In the Bible, Jesus refers to himself as "The wisdom of God" in Luke 11:49. Paul also refers to Christ as "the wisdom of God" in 1 Corinthians 1:24, and says that "in [Christ] are hidden all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge" in Colossians 2:3.

@JoshuaB - and the "Wisdom of God" also refers to the Scriptures in Luke 11:49; Ezra had the wisdom of God in his hand (Ezra 7:25).  1 Cor 1:30 says that Jesus BECAME the wisdom of God.  See also 1 Kings 3:28 for more.  things are not that simple - look at ALL the evidence.  In 1 Cor 1:21 the wisdom of God is distinct from Jesus.

@JoshuaB If you take Wisdom in Proverbs 8 as being just that, useful advice for proper living, it does have those effects. Foolishness ends up with people getting hurt or killed.

@JoshuaB It's dangerous to over-mythologize Scripture by saying that something that refers to Christ or God in one place must represent Christ or God in every other instance of that thing.

@JoshuaB Now, that's not to say that there's not applications that can be made concerning Christ as the Wisdom of God. There are. But that's not the primary meaning of Proverbs.

@JedSchaaf - In Luke 7:35, Jesus literally correlates himself as Wisdom incarnate.

@JoshuaB Yes, but that doesn't mean you can stick Jesus in everywhere you see wisdom referenced or anthropomorphized. That sort of thing will lead you pretty quickly into some weird heresies.

@JedSchaaf - If you don't mind me asking, what "weird heresies" do you imply?

@JoshuaB One was mentioned earlier in this comment chain: treating Jesus as female in some cases. S/He apparently (Prov. 8:12) lives with Prudence (who's that?) and figures out how things work (does He not already know?). Another involves James 1:5 - does that refer to salvation (wisdom is Jesus), or to an ability to decide hard things correctly (wisdom is wisdom)? Etc. You can make up a lot of strange stuff with that sort of jam-everything-together interpretive method.

@JedSchaaf Of course Jesus was not a female. But he had the feminine force of wisdom in his mind. Just my two cents. "Humble yourself like a child and you will enter the kingdom of God".
